# Simply search a string in entire netbeans solution

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there a way to find the entire solution for a string in netbeans.
I believe that there is a find [      ] tab to find a word in the .java file but looking to find the word in the entire solution.

p.s. Not to find and replace.

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: This can be done for any programming language in netbeans, whether java, php or any other.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Click
- Edit 
- Find in Projects

or ctrl + shift + F

Can enter the containing text and the scope
- Open Projects
- Main Project
- Selection

Comment: Was looking for exactly that when i posted the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the project in the projects pane.

Then press and hold Ctrl+Shift+H

A find and replace window will come up where you can specify what you would like to find and what to replace it with. You can use regular expressions and then after you search you can walk through all the results in the different files that are returned.

Answer (score 1):

On the mac it is `cmd + shift + f` (but you have to select the project on the projects pane, otherwise it doesn't work) or `Toolbar --> Edit --> Find in Projects`.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> is the shortest way.

You can define the wildcard there.

Answer (score -2):

Press `Ctrl + Shift + H`.

On the screen appear option `scope`. Click on this text-box and choose the project you want to find needed text snippets, or you can find all of the projects.
I am using `Netbeans 8.1`
Best regard !