# What could be the reason that the body tag of my webpage is getting populated by a deformed function from unknown source?

Tags: html, onload

[image]

I have been unable to locate such a function anywhere in my whole javascript folder and neither do I have this function written inline in the home.php file which is the file which contains this body tag.

Comment: This looks like malformed client-side code being generated by incorrect server-side code.  `$_SESSION` is a PHP concept, not a JavaScript one.  And that first attribute on `body` is entirely wrong, and looks like it came from some server-side value that was parsed incorrectly.

Comment: there are might be some javascript which create element and atttaching it to the body element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear I was unable to find from where was the unknown malformed function appearing in the body tag.

I am using Netbeans IDE and SO helped to find the function by this name in the entire project folder. It turned out that my home.php's `body` tag was getting merged with an interior subfile's `body` tag.

Below is the SO post that helped search me for search string in entire project.

[Simply search a string in entire netbeans solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037686/simply-search-a-string-in-entire-netbeans-solution)

> Click - Edit - Find in Projects
>
> or ctrl + shift + F
>
> Can enter the containing text and the scope - Open Projects - Main
>   Project - Selection